# How to roll-your-own live CD for safe home browsing

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, linux-distributions, livecd

I'm interested in booting-off-flash (i.e. like livecd) for more secure online banking at home.

- I like System Rescue CD, but AFAIK it doesn't have the wifi drivers. (These are convenient)
- Ubuntu LiveCD has the wi-fi drivers, but also has a lot of stuff I don't need
- I'd like a way to save some basic config settings (e.g. wifi SSID and passphrase), so that wifi works upon startup, i.e. without having to re-enter the settings.

What's the best way to 'roll my own slightly-customized boot-from-flash live cd?

Comment: Not an answer, but there are some things here you might want to think about from a similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/52834/how-safe-is-this-computer-from-intrusion/

Comment: (I wish the OP was a user here; they'll probably never see this question.) Could you explain how it is that booting to a live CD will provide more secure online banking for you? You'll still be using WiFi which means you'll still be relying upon whatever security currently set for the router. Anyone else know how this would be more secure?

Comment: @Micheal Todd: IMO, is a matter of time: I mean, if you connect to your wi-fi using a live environment which you keep with yourself, the possible attempts to steal your data are jailed to your "live banking session"; so, only if one already knows you'll be banking from say 10 a.m. to 10:20 a.m. should try to do it...besides, if a thief is after your data, you'll never be safe! :D

Answer (score 1):

I like this answer but as the poster notes, it's incomplete:

[Ubuntu live CD and installing new applications onto a USB drive](https://superuser.com/questions/50541/ubuntu-live-cd-and-installing-new-applications-onto-a-usb-drive)

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Slax](http://www.slax.org/), too.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will not fit your needs completely (maybe not at all) but I would suggest to do a common GNU/Linux installation, just a little bit ... "not that common"!

If you have a free partition to install a GNU/Linux OS, you can encrypt the whole / partition, and put your /boot partition inside your thumb drive: then you have just to select which wares you want on it (I'd suggest a custom Ubuntu Server installation or an ArchLinux installation as well).

What about that? Could it do the trick?

If not, and if you want a booting live USB thumb drive in a blink, you'll surely find a great deal in [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)!